# How to disable or remove AppXSVC

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-services

- I have noticed that this service `AppXSVC` starts automatically whenever I start `Firefox` my default browser (but not with chrome)!
- is there anyway to completely disable or remove this service? thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the Store service and should not be disabled. It does not cause issue on any machine here.   https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2bc8708-3a21-4b07-abf6-e9359e3e7961/appx-deployment-service-appxsvc-always-runs-at-startup-despite-set-as-manual-how-comes?forum=win10itprosetup

Comment: @John I accept to have some issues rather than feeling that Microsoft is running their services and updates by force!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Is there anyway to completely disable or remove this service (`AppXSVC`)?

The first thing to note is that it has nothing to do with `FireFox`:

> **What Is `wsappx`?**
>
> The `wsappx` process includes two seperate background services. On
> both Windows 8 and 10, `wsappx` includes the AppX Deployment Service
> (`AppXSVC`). On Windows 10, you’ll also see the Client License Service
> (`ClipSVC`). On Windows 8, you’ll also see the Windows Store Service
> (`WSService`) instead of `ClipSVC`.

Source: [What Is “wsappx” and Why Is It Running on My PC?](https://www.howtogeek.com/320261/what-is-wsappx-and-why-is-it-running-on-my-pc/)

> This service is started on demand and if disabled Store applications will not be deployed to the system, and may not function properly.

Source: [AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC) always runs at Startup despite set as Manual. How comes?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2bc8708-3a21-4b07-abf6-e9359e3e7961/appx-deployment-service-appxsvc-always-runs-at-startup-despite-set-as-manual-how-comes?forum=win10itprosetup)

The above link contains instructions to disable it but if you do so **Store applications will not be deployed to the system, and may not function properly** as noted previously

Comment: accually who care about bloatware from microsoft, that solve my issue and this process stop use 30% of cpu

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\AppXSvc]
"Start"=dword:00000004

Comment: thanks, I just don't use apps from so called "microsoft store".

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Edit next keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\AppXSvc\Start  set value to 4.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Clipsvc\Start  set value to 4.
```

reboot

source: https://www.jihosoft.com/windows-tips/fix-wsappx-100-disk-windows-10.html (see method #2).

Sorry, no official documentation mentioned here because microsoft removes any mention of how to bypass their harmful services

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).